# aws product api: what is the correct regional location and url for us west 2

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-product-api, ondemand

I am using boto3 pricing client to get on-demand pricing as boto3 ec2 client doesn't have on-demand but spot pricing.

This gives me error saying `Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://api.pricing.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/`.

What is the correct region name or location value below for us west 2. I check ed the regions and this is the correct one. Does pricing api isn't in Oregon region?

```
        pricing = boto3.client('pricing', region_name='us-west-2')
        response = pricing.get_products(
        ServiceCode='AmazonEC2',
        Filters=[
            {'Type': 'TERM_MATCH', 'Field': 'operatingSystem', 'Value': 'Linux'},
            {'Type':'TERM_MATCH', 'Field': 'location', 'Value': 'US West (Oregon)'}

        ],
        MaxResults=20
    )

    for price in response['PriceList']:
        resp = json.loads(price)
        on_demand = resp['terms']['OnDemand']
        print len(on_demand)
        print(on_demand)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are only two services endpoints supported by the AWS Price List Service API:

- https://api.pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
- https://api.pricing.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com

You will need to pick from one of those. us-west-2 is not supported.

Comment: Correct. See: [AWS Regions and Endpoints - Amazon Web Services](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html) The pricing information returned will still contain pricing for all regions. It is just the endpoint that is not in all regions.